# Stop elements resizing after new data added?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a simple chatroom app with Express/Jade/socket.io. Unfortunately my html/css knowledge isn't great. I've been using bootstrap and I have the app working. The problem is that when the screen loads for the first time (or on any subsequent refreshes) data is passed from the server to the Jade template and used to update 2 button badges and the panel-title. When this happens, all 3 elements first clear all values, then populate them, causing them to shift position, shown [here](http://cl.ly/image/2b3L3K0S1T3U)

What do I need to change to stop this? Should I be setting positions via CSS? I experimented with `absolute`, `static`, and `fixed` but to no avail. I also thought of pre-populating the elements with some initial dummy text, which would make them the correct size, and then set the text to hidden, overwriting it with the new data passed from the server, but this seems really clunky and I'm sure there is a neat way of doing it, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Maybe you could add a min-width to your buttons that is the size of the button plus the size of the badge. That way they wouldn't change size and position.

Comment: I would probably hide them all together on initial page load, and fade in sequentially as the data loads using javascript. Naturally keeping the horizontal space with min-height left for them, so no jumping of the content underneath happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set min-width for buttons and min-height for panel-title e.g.

```
#button1 {min-width: 120px;}
#button2 {min-width: 100px;}
```

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. As it happens my solution was even more straightforward. I was foolish to overlook it. I always have a default value of at least 1 room, and 1 user so by setting values initially it stops the elements resizing when the value changes